# Angular 2 how to make auth guard work with observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular2-guards

I'm trying to implement an auth guard to one of my routes but I can't get it to work since I'm not sure how to do it with an observable.

I use `ngrx/store` to store my token and then in the guard I fetch it using `this.store.select('auth')`, which fetches an object that looks like this (if you're logged in):

```
{
  token: 'atokenstring',
  isAuthenticated: true,
  isPending: false
}
```

And the guard looks like this:

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private store: Store<IStore>) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<any> {

    return this.store.select('auth').let((state: Observable<IAuthStorage>) => state.filter((auth: IAuthStorage) => !auth.isPending && auth.isAuthenticated)).map(
      (auth: IAuthStorage) => {

        if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
          return this.router.navigateByUrl('admin/login');
        }
        else {
          return true;
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Now, the problem appears to be that the guard returns an observable rather than a boolean value. Which causes the route not to render even if you get inside the `else` which returns `true`.

How can I make it so that the guard returns a boolean value rather than an observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this still is the case but a while ago something like this was required

```
  canActivate(): Observable<any> {

    return this.store.select('auth').let((state: Observable<IAuthStorage>) => state.filter((auth: IAuthStorage) => !auth.isPending && auth.isAuthenticated)).map(
      (auth: IAuthStorage) => {

        if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
          return this.router.navigateByUrl('admin/login');
        }
        else {
          return true;
        }
      }
    ).first(); // <<<=== added
  }
```

for the router only to wait for one event, not for the observable itself to complete.

`first` needs to be imported to be available.

Comment: Nice, appears you can use take as well without the need to import it. Thanks man.

Comment: Perhaps you have another import that covers it. You can import all at once or only what you use. Glad to hear it solves your issue.

Comment: I only import `Observable` from the rxjs lib, not sure if it's included automatically with that import. Don't really care as long as it's working :P

Comment: Actually, I don't know. I don't use TS myself. Just what I remember from what was asked/answered on other questions.

Comment: Actually it isn't working as expected when you're not authenticated, it never enters the map at all. I think it's because I do `!auth.isPending && auth.isAuthenticated`, but even if I remove `isAuthenticated` I can't get it to enter, whether doing `!auth.isPending` or `auth.isPending`.. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps there is no event where `!auth.isPending && auth.isAuthenticated` results to `true`?

Comment: Ye that's why I removed the latter part of that condition, but it still doesn't result to true whether `isPending` is false or true.. which I think is odd

Comment: Hard to tell from here :/

Comment: `first()` might have solved the issue actually.. Anyway I'll accept since this is a completely different issue.